# How to capitalize the first letter of each sentence with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capitalize first letter of each sentence and than replace the textarea's value with modified but i think there is some problem in my code.

```
$( ".question" ).blur(function() {
    var question = $(this).val().match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
    question.forEach(function(entry) {
        entry = entry.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + entry.substring(1);
        $('.question').val(entry)
    });

});
```

Comment: try `question.each` instead of `question.forEach`. If this doesn't work, could you give some more details about the error you're getting/what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K25eU/1/) to demonstrate the working code, but the gist of it is that you were replacing the value one at a time instead of creating one big value with the full contents of the textarea.

Here is the working javascript:

```
$( ".question" ).blur(function() {
  var question = $(this).val().match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
  var out = '';
  question.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry = entry.trim();
    entry = entry.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + entry.substring(1);
    out += entry + ' ';
  });
  $('.question').val(out.trim());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function capitalizeSentences(capText, capLock)
{
    if (capLock == 1 || capLock == true)
    {
        capText = capText.toLowerCase();
    }

    capText = capText.replace(/.n/g, ".[-<br>-]. ");
    capText = capText.replace(/.sn/g, ". [-<br>-]. ");
    var wordSplit = '. ';

    var wordArray = capText.split(wordSplit);

    var numWords = wordArray.length;

    for(x = 0; x < numWords; x++)
    {
        wordArray[x] = wordArray[x].replace(wordArray[x].charAt(0), wordArray[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
        if (x == 0)
        {
            capText = wordArray[x] + ". ";
        }
        else if(x != numWords - 1)
        {
            capText = capText + wordArray[x] + ". ";
        }
        else if(x == numWords - 1)
        {
            capText = capText + wordArray[x];
        }
    }
    capText = capText.replace(/[-<br>-].s/g, "n");
    capText = capText.replace(/sis/g, " I ");
    return capText;
}
```

And Invoke it by this way:

```
var txt = $('textarea#thetextfieldID').val();
txt = capitalizeSentences(txt, true);
$('textarea#thetextfieldID').val(txt);
```

Comment: Why just don't link to [source](http://www.bensprotips.com/2011/01/capitalizing-the-first-letter-of-each-sentence-in-javascript/)?